# Retrieve Iist Item column values with column names on Item click, JavaScript

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

I need to retrieve List item column values with column names on item click. In SP2010, I have a XSL which calls the JavaScript. I have sent the list item id through the XSL into the JavaScript function.

```
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());
pdfItem = list.getItemById(pdfItemID);  
context.load(pdfItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function(sender, args) {
        currentItemGUID = pdfItem.get_item('UniqueId');
    },
    function(sender, args) {
        alert('Request Failed' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }, "sp.js");
```

`pdfItem.get_schemaXml();` didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can get column/fields name from list unless they are not consistent and then use them to fetch values for each key, here's how you can get all fields for a list,

```
function loadFieldCustProperty() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List Title');
        fieldCollection = targetList.get_fields();
        clientContext.load(fieldCollection);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);


        function onQuerySucceeded() {

            var fe = fieldCollection.getEnumerator();
            while (fe.moveNext()) {
                var  field = fe.get_current();

                var xmlSchemaString = field.get_schemaXml();
                var fieldXml = parseXml(xmlSchemaString);
                var fieldElement = fieldXml.getElementsByTagName('Field')[0];
                var fieldPropertyValue = fieldElement.getAttribute('ColName'); //get ColName property value

                //...
            }

        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            //error handling goes here...
        }

    }
```

[View custom field property value using JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86106/view-custom-field-property-value-using-javascript)

Then, in here

```
currentItemGUID = pdfItem.get_item('UniqueId'); // here use field names e.g. using a enumerator for getting each column's value for selected item.
```

Also you might want to look at this question [Javascript to get GUID from SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24584/javascript-to-get-guid-from-sharepoint)